# Fail to plot the graph properly with igraph in R

Tags: r, plot, social-networking, igraph

Given a data frame `df` as below:

```
df
v1             v2
tom            ben
lily           dick
ben            lily
ben            dick
.....
```

I tried to plot a network graph to linkage two names if they are in the same row, such as tom and ben, lily and dick,ben and lily and so on.

Besides that, I also have a data frame `df_size` to indicate the vertex size:

```
df_size
v1            v2
tom           10
lily          3
ben           1
dick          2
...
```

The vertex size should be proportional to their corresponding value in `v2`.

And the last data frame is to classify them into groups and the color of the vertex should be the same if they are from the same group.

```
df_colour
v1        v1
tom       A
lily      B
ben       A
dick      A
```

Now I have tried this code:

```
g = graph.data.frame(df)
plot(g,vertex.size = df_size$v2 )
```

But get a very bad result:

[image]

Now I'd like to set the edge length and color of vertex properly, and remove the arrow. Do you have any idea to solve it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: change layout of the graph, vertex size, cex

Answer (score 0):

Add to the `plot` function the commands `vertex.label.cex` and `vertex.label.degree`. Try with this:

```
plot(g, vertex.size=8, vertex.color = rainbow(10, .8, .8, alpha= .8),
vertex.label.color = "black", vertex.label.cex = 0.4, vertex.label.degree = -pi/2,
edge.arrow.size = 0.3, edge.arrow.width = 0.4, edge.color = "black")
```